# Android achartengine setDisplayChartValues not working for single value

Tags: android

I'm drawing a graph using achartengine linechart for my app.
      The graph is used to display insulin levels for specific date and time.
      I'm using XYMultipleSeriesRenderer and i showed chartvalues 
      using   setDisplayChartValues.
      The values are shown for more than one value i.e if user select insulin level
      for more than a day but it is not working when i plot a single value i.e if 
      user select only one date. Can anyone help for my problem?

```
   Code:   
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {

((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i))
                .setFillPoints(true);
((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i))
                .setDisplayChartValues(true);
     }
```

Comment: edit and arrange it in properway

Comment: @parvathy now i edited.To explain more i want to display the yaxis value on the plot on chart.We can set this by using setDisplayChartValues(true).It is working fine when im plotting many values.But if i have only one value plotted in the graph chartvalue is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This Link may be usefull for your question.
   it contains sample chart programs..

http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html

Note: Good Question, This problem is facing most of the developers while 
   putting x,y line chart....(like making diabetic app for see the monthly blood
   sugar level for staticstics analtsys )